# filestream read array to lines C#

Tags: c#, filestream

i'm veeeery new to this.
I'm supposed to write a file with an array (got that) and read the content in 7 lines, 11 bytes each (no idea how).

*In case you speak german, thats my assignment:
Die Konsolenausgabe soll in sieben Zeilen mit jeweils elf
Zeichen gegliedert werden – dies entspricht auch der vorstehenden Anordnung der Array-Elemente.
Beachten Sie aber, dass eine Zeile im Array aus 33 Zeichen besteht – Ihre Konsolenausgabe soll
hingegen elf Zeichen umfassen!*

here's what i have so far:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ESA_2
{
    class Program
    {
        public void ESA2In(string Path)
        {
            byte[] array = {32, 32, 67, 67, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                            32, 67, 32, 32, 67, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                            67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35,
                            67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                            67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35,
                            32, 67, 32, 32, 67, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                            32, 32, 67, 67, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32 };

            FileStream stream = File.Open(@"C:\users\...test.txt", FileMode.Create);
            stream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }

        public void ESA2Out(string Path)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"C:\users\...test.txt", FileMode.Open));
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            reader.Close();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Path = @"C:\users\...\test.txt";

            Program test = new Program();

            test.ESA2In(Path);
            test.ESA2Out(Path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your assignment doesn't even say something about filestream, only that you are supposed to print it to the console.

Comment: that's true, that's what i found in my book where the assignment is enclosed. we also learned about binary.writer, is that the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read your symbols back as string using `Read()` method.
For example,

```
public void ESA2Out(string Path)
{
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"C:\users\...test.txt", FileMode.Open)))
  {
    for (var lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < 7; lineNumber++)
    {
      string line = "";
      for (var charNumber = 0; charNumber < 11; charNumber++)
        line = line + (char)reader.Read();
      Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    reader.Close();
  }
}
```

BTW, it should print big 'C#', where 'C' is made out of 'C'-letter, and '#' of '#'-s.

Comment: thank you for your answer! With your code, the output is the array, just as i posted it. how should it convert into C and #?

Comment: My bad - thought `reader.Read()` returns `char`, but it returns `int`. Updated answer - added explicit `char` conversion.

Comment: that works! thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 1):

Quercus solution covers your question. I just wanted to provide you with the simpler solution that corresponds to the actual assignment. You were tasked with converting the binary output into char letters plus adding a newline after every 11th character. The wrinting and reading was not asked by your assignment.

```
byte[] array = {32, 32, 67, 67, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                32, 67, 32, 32, 67, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35,
                67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                67, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35,
                32, 67, 32, 32, 67, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32,
                32, 32, 67, 67, 32, 32, 32, 35, 32, 35, 32 };

string output = string.Empty;
for(int i = 0; i<array.Length; i++)
{
     if (i % 11 == 0) output += Environment.NewLine;
     output += (char)array[i];
}

Console.WriteLine(output);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! The full assignment asks for writing and reading, as i managed to code that, i did not post it. sorry for the misconseption!

Answer (score 0):

A shorter code

```
public void ESA2Out()
{
    ReadOnlySpan<char> chars = File.ReadAllBytes("test.txt")
        .Select(b => (char)b).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i += 11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(chars.Slice(i, 11)));
    }
}
```